# How to change keyboard in Android phone

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

We looked for apps that offers different keyboards but the one we are looking for is not here. I want to install the Sky Vega keyboard (To my knowledge, Sky Vega is a Korean phone available only in Korea) on a Samsung Android phone.

Could a copy/paste of the Sky Vega keyboard and drop it in the keyboard folder of our phone work ?

Anyone has an idea how to do that ?

Sky Vega keyboard : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my HTC One running 4.1, when you are in a text field drag the notifications bar down, then select "Choose input method". You will need to have enabled your keyboard in settings > keyboards & languages first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings>keyboards and languages

Enable your desired keyboard

Long press on a text input field and choose input method. And select your keyboard.